# Drush 7 @self picks configuration from aliases.drushrc.php randomly

Tags: 7, search, drush

I'm trying to index Search API Solr using Drush 7 on platform environments, but the `drush search-api-index` command is failing for a very strange reason.

There are clues of the problem below, but I'm not sure what to do next to figure this out.  This issue has me very stumped.

### 1. I've configured platform.sh-specific drushrc.php file, which sets up the --uri option correctly.

```
web@server:~/www$ drush st
 Drupal version                  :  7.59
 Site URI                        :  https://mysite.us-2.platformsh.site/
 Database driver                 :  mysql
 Database hostname               :  database.internal
 Database port                   :  3306
 Database username               :  user
 Database name                   :  main
 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful
 Drupal user                     :
 Default theme                   :  mysite_theme
 Administration theme            :  seven
 PHP executable                  :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration               :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
 PHP OS                          :  Linux
 Drush script                    :  /app/.global/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
 Drush version                   :  7.4.0
 Drush temp directory            :  /tmp
 Drush configuration             :  /app/www/sites/all/drush/drushrc.php
 Drush alias files               :  /app/www/sites/all/drush/aliases.drushrc.php
 Install profile                 :  mysite
 Drupal root                     :  /app/www
 Site path                       :  sites/default
 File directory path             :  sites/default/files
 Private file directory path     :  /app/private
 Temporary file directory path   :  /app/tmp
```

### 2. Drush DOES list the search api indexes correctly.

```
web@server:~/www$ drush search-api-list
 Id  Name                 Index                Server                     Type          Status    Limit
 1   Default node index   default_node_index   (none)                     Content       disabled  50
 34  Location Search      location_search      Solr Server (Platform.sh)  Content       enabled   50
 35  Page manager pages   page_manager_pages   Solr Server (Platform.sh)  Page manager  enabled   50
 36  Site General Search  site_general_search  Solr Server (Platform.sh)  Content       enabled   50
 37  Bookplates           bookplates           Solr Server (Platform.sh)  Content       enabled   50
 38  Staff Directory      staff_directory      Solr Server (Platform.sh)  Content       disabled  50


web@server:~/www$ drush search-api-status
 Id  Index                % Complete  Indexed  Total
 1   Default node index   -           0        0
 34  Location Search      0%          0        2187
 35  Page manager pages   0%          0        13
 36  Site General Search  0%          0        2187
 37  Bookplates           0%          0        2199
 38  Staff Directory      -           0        0
```

### 3. HOWEVER, trying to reindex with drush fails

```
web@server:~/www$ drush search-api-index
The index Default node index is up to date.                                                                                                        [ok]
Indexing a maximum number of 2187 items (50 items per batch run) for the index Location Search.                                                    [ok]
Command batch-process needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this  [error]
command.
The drush command 'batch-process 19730' could not be executed.                                                                                     [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.                                                                                       [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case you can select another site with a working
database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See
http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.
```

### 4. A clue as to what is wrong is then given, with the WRONG db creds and site uri!

```
Drush was attempting to connect to:
 Drupal version         :  7.59
 Site URI               :  mysite.local
 Database driver        :  mysql
 Database hostname      :  mysite.local
 Database port          :  3306
 Database username      :  mysite
 Database name          :  mysite
 PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  Linux
 Drush script           :  /app/.global/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
 Drush version          :  7.4.0
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :  /app/www/sites/all/drush/drushrc.php
 Drush alias files      :  /app/www/sites/all/drush/aliases.drushrc.php
 Drupal root            :  /app/www
 Site path              :  sites/default
```

### 5. How are the wrong parameters being passed?

It's almost as if it is passing the wrong parameters or a default drush alias to the index task from somewhere, but where? I've scanned the code for "mysite.local":

```
web@server:~/www$ grep -r mysite.local .
./sites/all/drush/aliases.drushrc.php:$aliases['mysite.local'] = array(
./sites/all/drush/aliases.drushrc.php:  'uri' => 'mysite.local',
./sites/all/drush/drushrc.php.example:$options['uri'] = 'http://mysite.local';
./sites/all/modules/custom/powell_res/powell_res.module:    if ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='localhost' || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='mysite.local') {
./sites/all/modules/custom/rc_res/rc_res.module:    if ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='localhost' || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='mysite.local') {
./sites/default/local.settings.php:      'host' => 'mysite.local',
./sites/default/settings.php:  'mysite.local' => 'local.settings.php',
```

I would think that the only relevant locations from above are ./sites/all/drush/aliases.drushrc.php,  ./sites/all/drush/drushrc.php.example, and ./sites/default/local.settings.php.  Neither of the later two should be included at runtime from drush cli. The contents of my ./sites/default/settings.php only include local.settings.php if `uri = mysite.local`.  This leaves only aliases.drushrc.php.  **Could a default alias of `@mysite.local` somehow be passed under the covers?**

FWIW, I also looked for possible hard-coded drush command-specific config options to the search-api-index command placed in another file but couldnt turn up anything useful.  There is a ./sites/all/drush/drushrc_shared.php file but this file doesn't appear to be loaded, nor does it contain any relevant command-specific settings or even a --uri option.

### 6. Debugging with `-vvv --debug`

From the output below, The first half of the command runs fine, but then at some point after it finds the drush command file for search_api_index, it internally runs another drush command via "Backend invoke", with the wrong settings.

```
    web@server:~/www$ drush search-api-index -vvv --debug
    Drush preflight prepare loaded autoloader at                         [preflight]
    /app/.global/vendor/autoload.php [0 sec, 2.6 MB]
    Starting Drush preflight. [0 sec, 2.6 MB]                                                                                                          [preflight]
    Cache HIT cid: 7.4.0-commandfiles-0-2cc326a65c41fdab5fcf2c6cb9fb2c3b [0.01 sec, 2.66 MB]                                                               [debug]
    Loading drushrc "/app/www/sites/all/drush/drushrc.php" into "drupal" scope. [0.03 sec, 4.66 MB]                                                    [bootstrap]
    Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.08 sec, 6.65 MB]                                                                                                          [bootstrap]
    Bootstrap to phase 5. [0.08 sec, 6.65 MB]                                                                                                          [bootstrap]
    Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.09 sec, 7.03 MB]                                                                                [bootstrap]
    Loading drushrc "/app/www/sites/all/drush/drushrc.php" into "drupal" scope. [0.09 sec, 7.03 MB]                                                    [bootstrap]
    Initialized Drupal 7.59 root directory at /app/www [0.09 sec, 7.03 MB]                                                                             [bootstrap]
    Find command files for phase 1 (max=5) [0.09 sec, 5.06 MB]                                                                                             [debug]
    Cache HIT cid: 7.4.0-commandfiles-1-05d40856b788e54ca64b35c99a2c1fd7 [0.09 sec, 5.06 MB]                                                               [debug]
    Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.09 sec, 5.07 MB]                                                                                [bootstrap]
    Initialized Drupal site mysite.us-2.platformsh.site at sites/default [0.09 sec, 5.07 MB]                     [bootstrap]
    Find command files for phase 2 (max=5) [0.09 sec, 5.07 MB]                                                                                             [debug]
    Cache HIT cid: 7.4.0-commandfiles-2-f17fc6bdab2f74278df75194ca483893 [0.09 sec, 5.07 MB]                                                               [debug]
    Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.1 sec, 5.3 MB]                                                                         [bootstrap]
    Find command files for phase 3 (max=5) [0.1 sec, 5.34 MB]                                                                                              [debug]
    sql-query: SELECT 1; [0.1 sec, 5.45 MB]                                                                                                               [notice]
    Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_8YlZWK --database=main --host=database.internal --port=3306 --silent  < /tmp/drush_WhdxK8
      1
    sql-query: SHOW TABLES; [0.11 sec, 5.45 MB]                                                                                                           [notice]
    Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_I34QoZ --database=main --host=database.internal --port=3306 --silent  < /tmp/drush_INSUan
      [output redacted for brevity]
    Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_database() [0.14 sec, 5.54 MB]                                                                            [bootstrap]
    Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [0.15 sec, 6.07 MB]                                                                                 [bootstrap]
    Find command files for phase 4 (max=5) [0.15 sec, 6.07 MB]                                                                                             [debug]
    Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_full() [0.15 sec, 6.07 MB]                                                                                [bootstrap]
    Cache HIT cid: 7.4.0-install_profile-66ecfeb9791a023150773849f1550c5d [0.45 sec, 40 MB]                                                                [debug]
    Find command files for phase 5 (max=5) [0.45 sec, 40 MB]                                                                                               [debug]
    Cache HIT cid: 7.4.0-install_profile-66ecfeb9791a023150773849f1550c5d [0.45 sec, 40.01 MB]                                                             [debug]
    Cache HIT cid: 7.4.0-commandfiles-5-30eb6a40e5b156e214df63a4a8fcfecc [0.45 sec, 40.06 MB]                                                              [debug]
    Bootstrap to phase 6. [0.51 sec, 44.05 MB]                                                                                                         [bootstrap]
    Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_login() [0.51 sec, 44.06 MB]                                                                              [bootstrap]
    Find command files for phase 6 (max=6) [0.54 sec, 41.45 MB]                                                                                            [debug]
    Found command: search-api-index (commandfile=search_api) [0.54 sec, 41.45 MB]                                                                      [bootstrap]
    Calling hook drush_search_api_index [0.59 sec, 44.46 MB]                                                                                               [debug]
    The index Default node index is up to date. [0.61 sec, 45.96 MB]                                                                                   [ok]
    Indexing a maximum number of 2187 items (50 items per batch run) for the index Location Search. [0.61 sec, 45.96 MB]                               [ok]
    Cache HIT cid: 7.4.0-alias-path--0e94eb35635a057777b446898cdd620b [0.62 sec, 46.11 MB]                                                                 [debug]
    Backend invoke: /usr/bin/php /app/.global/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php  --backend=2 --user=0 --verbose --debug --root=/app/www    [command]
    --uri=mysite.local  batch-process 19738 2>&1 [0.62 sec, 46.13 MB]
    /usr/bin/php /app/.global/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php  --backend=2 --user=0 --verbose --debug --root=/app/www                     [notice]
    --uri=mysite.local  batch-process 19738 2>&1 [0.62 sec, 46.13 MB]
```

### 7. I've found a related [issue #1550575](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush/issues/1550574), but it claims to have been fixed for 6 years.

### 8.  Drush @self alias is being weird.

If I run `drush st` the output is correct (see #1 above). If I run `drush @self st` I get the WRONG db creds and site uri values:

```
web@server:~/www$ drush @self st
 Drupal version         :  7.59
 Site URI               :  mysite.local
 Database driver        :  mysql
 Database hostname      :  mysite.local
 Database port          :  3306
 Database username      :  mysite
 Database name          :  mysite
 PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  Linux
 Drush script           :  /app/.global/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
 Drush version          :  7.4.0
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :  /app/www/sites/all/drush/drushrc.php
 Drush alias files      :  /app/www/sites/all/drush/aliases.drushrc.php
 Drupal root            :  /app/www
 Site path              :  sites/default
```

### 9  drush sa @self randomly picks the wrong alias from aliases.settings.php

```
web@server:~/www$ drush sa @self
$aliases["mysite.local"] = array (
  'root' => '/app/www',
  'uri' => 'mysite.local',
  'path-aliases' =>
  array (
    '%dump' => '/app/db/local-20180830051250.sql',
  ),
  'command-specific' =>
  array (
    'sql-sync' =>
    array (
      'structure-tables-key' => 'custom',
      'structure-tables' =>
      array (
        'custom' =>
        array (
          0 => 'cache',
          1 => 'cache_block',
          2 => 'cache_bootstrap',
          3 => 'cache_field',
          4 => 'cache_filter',
          5 => 'cache_form',
          6 => 'cache_image',
          7 => 'cache_libraries',
          8 => 'cache_menu',
          9 => 'cache_page',
          10 => 'cache_path',
          11 => 'cache_search_api_solr',
          12 => 'cache_token',
          13 => 'cache_views',
          14 => 'cache_views_data',
          15 => 'history',
          16 => 'sessions',
          17 => 'watchdog',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'rsync' =>
    array (
      'mode' => 'rlptDz',
    ),
  ),
  'target-command-specific' =>
  array (
    'sql-sync' =>
    array (
      'enable' =>
      array (
        0 => 'stage_file_proxy',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

I suspected drush was picking the first alias defined from the `./sites/all/drush/aliases.drushrc.php` file, but when I added another different alias and changed the order, I confirmed that it does not do this. Thus, I don't understand why it decides to pull this specific one as the `@self`.

Comment: I don't know what specifically is wrong with your setup, but some notes:
- Drush 7 is no longer supported. You should use Drush 8.
- The Drush issue queue on drupal.org is no longer active; you should use https://github.com/drush-ops/drush
- Never use `drush @self cmd`; it is nonsensical. Aliases in the first position tell Drush which site to bootstrap. The `@self` alias is defined to be the site that Drush bootstrapped. Using `@self` in the first position is therefore circular. Drush should throw a hard error for this, but does not. You may use `drush sa @self` to see the selected site

Comment: Maybe try setting $base_url in settings.php and see if that works better.

Comment: Thanks @greg_1_anderson.   I get that I shouldn't use `@self` in real drush commands, but this *is exactly* what drush 7's backend invoke seems to be doing, so I figured i'd look to see what @self generated (hence item #8).  Thanks for tip about `drush sa @self` -- will add that output as point #9 above.

Comment: Setting $base_url did not have any effect for Drush 7, *however* updating to Drush 8 seems to have helped. I'll also point out that Drush 8 exhibits a similar issue running drush sa @self pulls the same alias from aliases.drushrc.php file, as mentioned in point #9 above. The only differences are that the first line of output doesn't reference the alias as it is named in the file: `$aliases["self"] = array (`and the 'uri' is magically set correctly, but all other lines are pulled from the `$aliases["mysite.local"]` entry. This is exceedingly odd.

Answer (score 1):

The only valid solution after discussing with greg anderson, drush maintainer, is to upgrade to Drush 8, where this issue seems to have been fixed.